# Replace method in C# not working for individual character?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I've been looking around and it seems like I'm using this properly, but the results are failing.  I want to go through and get rid of any 0's and replace them with o's.

```
newString = strOld.Replace('0', 'o'); // doesn't work.

newString = strOld.Replace("0", "o"); // doesn't work either.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have any sample data that you use which shows this doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, are you running different culture/locale settings? The Replace method is ordinal based, but culture insensitive.

Comment: can you give an example of an `strOld` for which the method is failing?

Comment: Umm, replacing 0s with a lowercase o makes about as much sense as replacing the number 4 with the letter M. Are you sure that you really want to do this? And can you explain what *specifically* you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: The program is to check and prevent users from using bad passwords that include dictionary words.  I wanted the program to fail when people try and use b00k because that's still a dictionary word and easy to break.

Answer (score 2):

I made this test, and it works fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newString = "M0000".Replace('0', 'o');
    }
}
```

Try a small test case, similar to the one I created, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out in order to use the replace method it had to go into the same string. So while this won't work:

```
String newString;

String oldString = "b00k";

newString = oldString.Replace('0', 'o');
```

---

This will work:

```
String newString = "b00k";

newString = newString.Replace('0', 'o');

Appreciate all the feedback.
```

Comment: Sounds like the real problem wad that your code that followed was using the wrong variable.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, actually just for information, I was doing something thing like `myOldString.Replace("#", "No.");`.
It was not working, I checked it.
Finally I found the solution, when i replaced the above string as 
`myOldString = myOldString.Replace("#","No");`
string.replace makes a replica, earlier i was not assigning that to the actual string.
Make sure you are not making such t

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here... the char version should work regardless of case if they were letters (I assume you're trying to replace zeroes with an lowercase O). Are you maybe using a font that does not distinguish between zero and the letter O or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong.  If you want to do a character replace instead of a string replace you need to do: `s.Replace(char.Parse("0"), char.Parse("o"))`, but I can't think of any reason your code doesn't work.

Comment: What does this accomplish over s.Replace('0', 'o') besides the extra overhead of creating strings and then parsing them back into chars?

Comment: Nothing.  But your question said to replace an individual character and I wanted to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows this very clearly: http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace 
If you use string.Replace, it has to be assigned (as mentioned above by Geeklat):

```
String newString = "b00k";
newString = newString.Replace('0', 'o');
```

If you use "StringBuilder" the variable not have to be assigned - 
Here is a Sample Program (Output is below):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
class Program
    {
    static void Main()
    {
    const string s = "This is an example.";

    // A
    // Create new StringBuilder from string
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
    Console.WriteLine(b);

    // B
    // Replace the first word
    // The result doesn't need assignment
    b.Replace("This", "Here");
    Console.WriteLine(b);

    // C
    // Insert the string at the beginning
    b.Insert(0, "Sentence: ");
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
This is an example.
Here is an example.
Sentence: Here is an example.
```